# Saving click data to an table (Processing)

Tags: processing

I´ve tried looking up the question but sadly I wasnt able to find my an answer to my question in other threads. :(

My problem is the following:

I´ve got my hands on a code which transfers clickdata into a heatmap.
Now what I would need is a way to transfer said clickdata into a table which documents the coordinates.
Here is the (hopefully) relevant part out of the code:

```java
void mouseReleased()
{
  if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX < backgroundImage.width && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY < backgroundImage.height)
  {
    // blit the clickmapBrush onto the (offscreen) clickmap:
    clickmap.blend(clickmapBrush, 0,0,clickmapBrush.width,clickmapBrush.height,mouseX-clickmapBrush.width/2,mouseY-clickmapBrush.height/2,clickmapBrush.width,clickmapBrush.height,BLEND);
    // blit the clickmapBrush onto the background image in the upper left corner:
    image(clickmapBrush, mouseX-clickmapBrush.width/2, mouseY-clickmapBrush.height/2);

    // render the heatmapBrush into the gradientMap:
    drawToGradient(mouseX, mouseY);
```

The code is used for the software "Processing".
I hope my question is specific enough.
Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: By a table you mean an HTML `<table>`?

Comment: Html table would be great! =)

Comment: Do you mean any kind of table, e.g. a CSV data text file / spreadsheet would also be fine? Please say more about what kind of table you need and what you plan on doing with it.

Comment: I´m mainly struggling with the concept of getting the mouseclick data into a Table / spreadsheet with coordinates I can review or put into a statistic.       Tried googling my problem but couldnt find a soloution I could work with / understand. :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample Processing sketch that will record a list of coordinates for each mouse click:

```java
// We will store a list of coordinates,
// each representing a single mouse click's position
ArrayList<PVector> clickData;

void setup() {
  clickData = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  // Do any aditional setup you need here
}

void draw() {
  // Do any drawing here
}

// Called after each press and release of the mouse
void mouseClicked() {
  // Add the mouse's position to our list of mouse click positions
  clickData.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}
```

If you want to get the x value of the first recorded mouse click, for example, you can access it through a call to `clickData.get(0).x`, which first grabs the PVector at position 0 from `clickData`, then get's the `x` value associated with that PVector object.

Hope that helps!

You can read about the PVector class [here](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html)